# On a planet without gravity, how can water stay on the surface?

Tags: science-in-society, sunlight, alternate-earth

In a fictional world that is round, and has no gravity, how would you go about making the water not fall off the planet (Or even people, for that matter?. Is there some kind of futuristic force field that can be implemented to keep the water (and people) in place?

Comment: So . . . I've edited the question to remove the claim that Earth is flat; that has no importance here. All that we care about is that somehow gravity as we know it does not exist in this universe. Of course, that gives you a load of other problems, but still. So, please refrain from claiming that Earth is flat and gravity is non-existent; it's pseudoscience and not important here. I've also done some comment cleanup. Let's move on.

Comment: @HDE226868 Thanks for that. Now OP should elaborate a bit, maybe add a tag or two I think.

Comment: In a fictional world where the earth is a sphere, I would make water a living entity with muscles, so like a snake, it could hold onto the earth's core.

Comment: How is this off topic? I'm trying to build a fictional spherical earth

Comment: One could have a planet sized object (bubble?  construct?) with a hollow center which would have a mass much less than a typical planet.  Methods for keeping liquid on the surface is a fun, fine question.  Fine edits by @HDE226868 and author very welcome.  Reopen!

Comment: Without gravity there is no force to propel water or people off a round planet. Admittedly jumping up in the air will be hazardous. No gravity means escape velocity is any finite velocity.

Comment: But if there is no gravity, how did the world form in the first place? That may give you your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming by round, you mean "flat-earth".

Just have the planet not be perfectly flat, but rather a dinner plate shape with the lip. Have the water and the people be inside the lip and you are fine.

Finally to explain the people/water sticking to the plate. Have you looked into the high tier pseudoscience that is "[Universal Acceleration](https://wiki.tfes.org/Universal_Acceleration)"?

> According to Flat Earth Theory, gravity is not the main force keeping
>   us on the ground. Instead, there is a force that produces identical
>   effects as observed from the surface of the earth. This force is known
>   as "Universal Acceleration" (abbreviated as UA).
>
> Objects on the earth's surface have weight because all sufficiently
>   massive celestial bodies are accelerating upward at the rate of 9.8
>   m/s^2. The mass of the earth is thought to shield the objects atop it
>   from the direct force of UA. Alternatively, it is possible that the
>   force of UA can actually pass through objects, but its effect on
>   smaller bodies is negligible (similar to gravity in RET cosmology,
>   which only has a noticeable affect on very large objects).

The shape of earth in your model.
[image]

Comment: Larry Niven suggests a world that shape, with a giant rocket strapped to the side on the table, as a building block for a Ringworld.

Answer (score 2):

You change the way gravity works.

You could get really esoteric or make it something as simple as an invisible sphere like a forcefield containing your flat World and work with that as a start.

Finally dispense with gravity as the main force and scale up atomic forces... you can either make it a tiny subatomic World, or describe the forces any way you like since scientists only have some vague theories. Stick it in another dimension.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [some magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), and your world not to experience any external force, so no acceleration, no orbiting around stuff and no impact from large object (most of this is solved by the lack of gravity, so here's that).

Also, having a star near your planet (which would holds together by actual, full blown magic) might induce currents in the water that will cause some of it to reach escape velocity... namely 0 m/s² in your universe. Oh, and the star is orbiting the planet... all thanks to [totally not gravity], and you even get to choose the name of that fictionnal force!

Houses are bolted to the ground, so are people (actually, don't bolt people to stuff, this process is known to hurt a bit)

Finally, nobody could rely on their sense of up and down, since that doen't exist, so house would not be upside down on the other side of the world. I think people would rely on the horizon to know which way is up, and closing your eyes might induce motion sickness!

EDIT: Well, since you postulate that the earth is immovable, that should mean infinite density, but without gravity I have no idea what that would do.

Comment: ahh yeah the currents caused by the wind that the sun makes when it is moving?

Comment: Now that I think of it, [convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) wouldn't work without gravity

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's easy, without gravity, water can't fall. Water is always in a round shape where there is no gravity.
It's always great to find another believer. Keep up the good work!

If that's not a good answer for you, I have another! Water is actually tons of nanomachines! They try to hold on to the Earth because they love the Earth. If you remove them from the Earth, they will try to fly back down.

Comment: please do not let this site become a childish discussion site with joke-questions and witty but not serious answers. this is not a forum. It's meant for serious questions regarding worldbuilding and not whatever this question and this answer are trying to be.

Comment: The water sticking to earth's surface could be explained with surface tension, although I can't really tell if it would work on that kind of scale :)

Comment: I did think of surface tension. i guess i could make the world and people small enough that surface tension would work

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question. And the answer works. If you don't like this kind of question (one that really makes you think), then go over on Meta and complain. The Mods have (unless they've changed their minds) what is essentially an anything goes policy towards allowable questions, so we all have to deal with whatever comes along!